# Creating Views from a large database on the basis of attributes in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, view

I have a large database comprising of different costs and revenues of different projects, line of business, geographical locations. What I need to do is to create views on the basis of different attributes such as geographical region, time period, projects, line of business.which gives the profit of each project followed by line of business and at last total profit of the organization all over the world. All have to be done in SQL-Server 2008.

Comment: What is your question? How to create a view?

Comment: I want to create different views categorized on the basis of attributes of geography, projects which shows  profit of each project taking into account all the cost and revenue then profit and aggregate them to find profit of business line, operational unit and finally profit of a geographical region.

Comment: It is not possible to give details on how to create such view(s) given the information in your post. I suggest that you create a minimal example with table definitions (create table statements), some sample data (insert statements) and a detailed explanation of what you would like the view to do. Many posters use sqlfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use inLine Views, these will reduce cost of running time.
Use Temporary Table to Update your results and then Put Result into your Main Table or View.
Given Query is Part of My View using inLine view.

```
 BEGIN
UPDATE (SELECT CCTP.BORRO_OCCUPATION,
               CCTP.BORRO_MARITAL_STS,
               CCTP.BORRO_EDU_LVL,
               OC.OCCUPATION_DSC,
               MSC.MARITAL_STATUS_DSC,
               AEC.EDUCATION_DESC
          FROM CALL_CENTRE_INFO_LIVE    CCTP,
               BP_INDIVIDUAL            BI,
               OCCUPATION_CODE          OC,
               MARITAL_STATUS_CODE      MSC,
               APPLICANT_EDUCATION_CODE AEC
         WHERE BI.BUSINESS_PARTNER_ID = CCTP.BORROWER_ID
           AND OC.OCCUPATION_CDE = BI.OCCUPATION_CDE
           AND MSC.MARITAL_STATUS_CDE = BI.MARITAL_STATUS_CDE
           AND AEC.EDUCATION_CDE = BI.EDUCATION_CDE) T

   SET T.BORRO_OCCUPATION  = T.OCCUPATION_DSC,
       T.BORRO_MARITAL_STS = T.MARITAL_STATUS_DSC,
       T.BORRO_EDU_LVL     = T.EDUCATION_DESC;
```

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      P_RETURN := -1;
      RETURN;
  END;

**CALL_CENTRE_INFO_LIVE** This is my Temp Table and this part of Code is Update Statement for Main Table.
Hope it will help you (though it is complex but very helpful).

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, I think a indexed/materialized view will help you a lot for performance point of view as it will have an index for your view and it also improve the performance for aggregate functions also.